# Classes from dependancy (Jar file) are not resolved resulting in compile error

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project that is currently working fine. I now need to add a Java library (packaged as Jar) as a dependency and use classes defined in the Jar file. This works fine if I use flatDir as a repository in build.gradle,

`repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir {
    dirs '../java_library/build/libs'
  }
}`

and then in the dependencies,

`compile name: "java_library-0.0.1"`

I can then easily import classes from the library into my own code, build is successful, everything works.

However I cannot do this on our build server so instead of referencing the jar from my local workspace, I need to fetch it from our organization's internal maven repository.

`maven {
    url 'http://customer_repo:0000/maven'
 }`

and then in dependencies,

`compile ('our.company.groupid:java_library:0.0.1')`

I have verified that the library is published to the local repository and that gradle does not say it was not able to fetch the dependency (it was giving one such error before the Jar was published to local repository).

But now when I build the project it given compile errors saying it did not find the symbol pointing to the class imported from the Jar library. The same error is shown in IDE (IntelliJ) which was also working fine with flatDir.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

SOLVED:
Yes there was one obvious thing that I was missing. In the JAR library project, build.gradle had the following,

`publishing {
    ...
    publications {
        artifactId = 'java_library'
    }
}`

I was missing

`from components.java`

as soon as I added it,

`publishing {
    ...
    publications {
        artifactId = 'java_library'
        from components.java
    }
}`

and published the library again I was able to import it successfully in the other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> url 'http://customer_repo:0000/maven'

First, open this URL in browser and ensure you can reach you library by clicking links (i.e. `our -> company -> groupid -> java_library -> 0.0.1`)

Second, download library and check it really includes missing class file. Probably, you uploaded wrong file which is not library.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was able to figure out the problem shortly after posting the problem. In build.gradle -> publishing section, I was missing 'from components.java'. Once this line was added jar was successfully published to repository and downloaded in the other project. Your answer is relevant as browsing repository would have yielded this information.